# Unity- Load - Unlock levels and check if there are next levels existing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on small game similar to angry birds since I am new to both unity
and C#. I want to make load and unlock next level if all enemies are dead and check if new level exist
(if not) return back to Level selection scene.

This is what I tried:

**LevelScript**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelScript : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField] string _nextLevelName;

Monster[] _monsters;




void OnEnable()
{
    _monsters = FindObjectsOfType<Monster>();
}


private void Update()
{
    int currentLevel = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex ;
   

    if (currentLevel >= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelsUnlocked"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("levelsUnlocked", currentLevel );
    }

    if (MonsterAreAllDead())
    {

        GoToNextLevel();

    }

    Debug.Log("Level" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelsUnlocked") + "UNLOCKED");
}






public void Pass()
{
    int currentLevel = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

    if (currentLevel >= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelsUnlocked") )
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("levelsUnlocked", currentLevel + 1);
       
    };

}
    
bool MonsterAreAllDead()
{

    foreach (var monster in _monsters)
    {
        if (monster.gameObject.activeSelf)
            return false;

    }

    return true;
}


void GoToNextLevel()
{
    Debug.Log("Go to next level" + _nextLevelName);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(_nextLevelName);


}
```

}

and **Level Manager**

```
 public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    int levelsUnlocked;



    public Button[] buttons;

    
    void Start()
    {
        levelsUnlocked = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelsUnlocked", 1);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].interactable = false;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < levelsUnlocked; i++)
        {




            buttons[i].interactable = true;



    }
    }

    




public void LoadLevel(int levelIndex)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelIndex);
    
    }
```

I got these 2 scripts and I attached both canvas and my buttons and Level script to my levels.

Problem is that every level gets unlocked at begin and after completeing levels automatically
it want to go to next level whic is not exist yet.

Pls help me. Sorry if my question is stupid and for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

You should make an array of scene in your LevelManager that know all your levels (in order)
and for getting next level you can get the position of your actual scene in the array and check the next one.

somethink like

pseudocode :

```
[Serialized]
Scene[] AllScenes

void GoToNextLevel()
{
    int currentLevelPos = AllScenes.IndexOf(currentScene);
    if (AllScenes[currentLevelPos + 1] != null)
          Load Next Level
    else
         Go To Level Menu
}
```

Comment: Can you please try to explain what to put in  IndexOf() ?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html